# Corrupted OOTB Workflows Feature from SP2007 to SP2010 Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, feature

We recently performed a database detach upgrade method and the out of the box workflows:
Approval, Collect Feedback and Collect Signatures are all missing from the Workflow Templates when trying to add a workflow.

Those three workflows are from the "Workflows" feature that is out of the box SharePoint 2010 and once activated, those workflows will show up. However, when I de-activate and re-activate that feature in my upgraded site collections, the workflow templates are corrupted. They do not show up in the GUI (I think they do but their names are blank, and are unselectable).

If I open the site in SharePoint Designer I can see the workflows in the site, but they are corrupted, there are no forms associated, their names default to "Workflow 1", etc.

If I create a new site collection in this SharePoint 2010 environment, the workflows show up fine in the new site collection.

How do I fix the corrupted OOTB "Workflows" feature in my upgraded site collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up just using SharePoint Designer to delete the corrupted workflows and re-activating the OOTB "Workflows" feature again and it seems to work.